# Why won't Gluon Mobile Sample App run on iPad Air 2 yet run on iPhone?

Tags: javafxports, gluon-mobile

When using the gradle launchIOSDevice task within the GluonMObile-MultiViewProjextwithFXML demo project from InteliJ IDEA 16, get a Failure: Build failed with an exception.  ApplicationVerficationFailed.

Same App runs fine on iOS iPhone 9.3 but iPad Air2 on 9.3 gives error.

Android also builds and runs fine so something specific it seems with the iPad.

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':launchIOSDevice'..............
.......
Caused by: org.robovm.libimobiledevice.LibIMobileDeviceException: ApplicationVerificationFailed
    at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher$1.error(AppLauncher.java:1001)
```

Comment: Have you tested other Gluon apps on that iPad? Make sure you add your package name as well as other third party dependencies to the `forceLinkClasses` command.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that

- The **app.id** parameter in the **robovm.properties** matches your created App ID
- The same **app.id** is used in **Info.plist** (/src/ios/assets/Info.plist).

> ```
> <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
> <string>[Put here your app.id]</string>
> ```